# How to do this simple math in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a db column called timestamp which is exactly what it holds. I want to get the sum of the timestamp and 10 days. How will that query look?

In other words how can I say this in:

```
SHOW ME THE RESULT OF TIMESTAMP + 10 DAYS;
```

in working sql syntax of course :)

Comment: SELECT (Timestamp+10*24*60*60) AS Result FROM Table

Comment: is it a MySQL timestamp or a UNIX timestamp? those are different

Comment: Why couldn't you have just read the documentation or Googled it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`timestamp`, INTERVAL 10 DAY) FROM `table`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 day);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ADDDATE(timestamp, 10) from tablename;
```